# How do I get my site name next to the main site like button, instead of 'this'?

Tags: facebook, fbml

Yet another silly facebook "like" button question. We have a main like button for our website, which is basically the like button with text to its right resembling "x,x,x and xx others like this."

What I want is to change the text to "x,x,x and xx others like Example", where Example is the name of the site.

I have included the six Open Graph meta tags, and the like button is generated by the following FBML:

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com/" layout="standard" show_faces="yes"></fb:like>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Is that possible at all?

Comment: @alex - I got the idea from this site: http://www.eventfinder.co.nz/ so I guess it is.

Comment: @karim79 Neat! I assume you have `<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site" />` in your `head` element?

Comment: @alex - I don't. And if you are correct, I will fly to wherever you are, and give you five pounds of premium fillet steak.

Comment: @alex - unfortunately I will not get to test until I'm at work. My Spidey sense tells me it will though :) And for the love of god, post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding...

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site" />
```

...in your `head` element. :)